# API to get android google play reviews(Getting device name and app version)

Tags: android, google-play

I want to retrieve all the reviews for a specific app on google play and I need these informations from the reviews : rating, comment, device name and app version the review was wrote for.

I tried to use the android-market-api but sadly I can only get rating, creationtime, authorname, text, authorid.

So I was wondering if there is an API or an url I can send a post or get request (like the android-market-api send a post request) to retrieve the information I need.

Answer (score 16):

Finally Google offers it now (announced at [Google I/O 2016](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/whats-new-in-google-play-at-io-2016.html)):

[Google Play Reviews API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews)

Comment: Any way to get the reviewers google plus id or profile url?

Also can be get reviews from any app or only one which we have access of?

Comment: @Jing Li Correct me if I am wrong: shall I be the publisher of the app in order to have access to the reviews using the APIs? Or as external user can I have access to it?

Comment: @VivekSancheti I was actually searching for the same. We can only fetch the reviews of our own app and not for any app on the store.

Comment: @Siva So did you find a way to fetch other apps review api?

Comment: Is there any way to get detail other than reviewer name and comment, such as app version and phone/device type? _Edit: sorry! I see the "comment" section had device details._

Answer (score 12):

An example in Python with new [Reviews API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/python/latest/androidpublisher_v2.reviews.html) using [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) credentials.

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    '<secret from service account>.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'])

service = build('androidpublisher', 'v2', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

package_name = "<package name>"
reviews_resource = service.reviews()
reviews_page = reviews_resource.list(packageName=package_name, maxResults=100).execute()
reviews_list = reviews_page["reviews"]

infinite_loop_canary = 100
while "tokenPagination" in reviews_page:
    reviews_page = reviews_resource.list(packageName=package_name,
                               token=reviews_page["tokenPagination"]["nextPageToken"],
                               maxResults=100).execute()
    reviews_list.extend(reviews_page["reviews"])
    infinite_loop_canary -= 1
    if infinite_loop_canary < 0:
        break
```

Keep in mind - I found out, Reviews API only allow access to last two weeks comments-ratings. If you want to do some retroactive analysis it is better to get comments-ratings as csv files from where they are saved in your account's bucket on google-cloud.

Comment: Using Google review API, can we see any app's review or is it only possible to see reviews of the apps that I developed ?

Comment: As the reviews API requires authentication and is mapped to the project, you can only see apps from your google play developer account

Comment: Can you provide same code for PHP also. Same for PHP using service account

Comment: @auselen Can you provide same code for PHP also. Same for PHP using service account

Comment: Google currently only provides reviews up to 1 week old now, rather than 2. There's a helpful guide online https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews

Answer (score 2):

I am currently also searching for the same thing. Although its an old thread but just thought to share my research so far in this domain which might be helpful for other visitors.

commercial

- https://42matters.com/api/lookup

open-source

- https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ Java
- https://github.com/MarcelloLins/GooglePlayAppsCrawler C#
- https://github.com/chadrem/market_bot Ruby
- https://github.com/Akdeniz/google-play-crawler Java
- https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api Python

**Update :**

http://www.playstoreapi.com/docs#app_info (unavailable now !) but instead you can give a try to https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API/

Comment: http://www.playstoreapi.com/ redirects to Play Store website. Any idea why? Did they change the URL?

Comment: Strange ! Yes, it doesn't exist anymore and I have no idea why. I did a google search and found this https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API which might be of help for you.

Answer (score 1):

So when people start to answer this question they are going to point you to the following API:

Title: android-market-api.
link: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Unfortunately this API is mediocre and has some problems that I don't think are related to the developers of the API but the interaction with google.

I have used this API and the application I wrote works for finding some app's and their metadata but others it just returns no results. 
I have been searching for an answer to this for a while and I have yet to figure it out.

Good luck

Comment: Ya, like i said I already tried this api but it did not give me the results I wanted. The only way that I have found to maybe be able to do it is with a html scrapper on your on android developer page. Sadly I have no idea if google accept to do that kind of operation on their android Dev page. So for now I will just keep using the API since the other info was only a new nice feature.

Comment: @alexis did u find any other api to fetch reviews? is there a way to fetch reviews from amazon products?

Comment: yes and no, the api would find some of the apps and not others so if I couldn't find the app I couldnt get the review.  as far as the amazon reviews go I'm not sure.

Comment: As i think, this api is able to find only 10 reviews of any app, does you know how do i get all reviews of given app

Comment: the API gives you 'n' results per page based on the parameter you pass into it.  you can either increase the page size or loop until you have all of the pages at a given size. In the folloowing the entry count is your page size and the start index is your page number. CommentsRequest.newBuilder()
.setAppId("7065399193137006744").setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10).build();
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the information to be realtime, you can download the Google Play Reports from google cloud storage. The reports are built daily.

See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?p=crash_export&rd=1#export

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting apis released for getting reviews and reply on google play. You can get the all the data you want:

```
    "device": string,
    "androidOsVersion": integer,
    "appVersionCode": integer,
    "appVersionName": string
```

---

**get**  GET 
Returns a single review based on review id.
**list**
Returns a list of reviews from playstore.
**reply**
Reply to a single review, or update an existing reply.

[More here.](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews#resource-representations)