# Is there a way to fetch my app's latest reviews and stars in google play through api?

Tags: android

I want to fetch my app's latest reviews and stars

And I find the google cloud storage's save (buckets begin with pubsite_prod_rev) is not the latest

Is there a way to fetch my app's latest reviews and stars in google play through api?

Comment: This has already answered. Check [this][1] and [this][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348025/api-to-get-android-google-play-reviewsgetting-device-name-and-app-version
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017291/is-there-an-official-api-for-the-google-play-store-app

Answer (score 0):

Playstore API returns the average score and top reviews. Free tier provides up to 100 calls per month.

http://www.playstoreapi.com/docs#app_info