# Can we get the Rating(Review) of the user of the app by app itself?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

What I mean is to get the the Rating(Review) in Google Play of the app's user.
I am wondering if this is possible and it could be used to remind users to rate in Google Play, if they didn't do it before.

Comment: I thought I'd also mention it took me 15 seconds to find that duplicate using words copied from the question as search terms in Google. #justsaying

Comment: take a look at this question might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348025/api-to-get-android-google-play-reviewsgetting-device-name-and-app-version